# How to find the PDF from the CDF?

Tags: statistics

I have the following CDF:

F(x)=
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } x < 4 \\
\frac{x-4}{4} & \text{if } 4 \le x < 8 \\
1 & \text{if } x \ge 8
\end{cases}

I know that the PDF is equal to the first derivative of the CDF.
But taking the first derivative of it would just be 1/4. That can't right because not everything between 4 and 8 can be .25. What am I missing or not seeing? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: this is the right answer. The PDF is constant on [4,8] and 0 otherwise

Comment: "[N]ot everything between $4$ and $8$ can be $.25$." Why do you think this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the right answer.  The PDF = 1/4 on the range [4,8) and is zero elsewhere.

Comment: But if lets say at x=4.2 its .25, and at x=4.4 its .25, etc., then wouldn't the cdf end up being greater than 1?

Comment: And the reason I think that's important, is because the problem continues asking us to find P(x<7) using only the pdf.

Comment: No it would not, the PDF is a pulse on the range [4,8) with constant value .25.The CDF gives the P(X <= x) and is the area under the curve.  So for x >= 8 the CDF = 1, for x = 4 it's 0, and in between it's a linear shot between the two, which is exactly what you described in your question

Comment: The P(X < 7) using the PDF is the integral of the PDF from -inf to 7.  In this case it would be (7-4) * .25 = .75.  Everywhere else the PDF is 0 so the area under the curve is 0

Comment: Ok, I think I'm starting to piece this together. I kept thinking of this pdf in the same way as when I learned about it in the noncontinous way. When it was just descrete variables. And I think thats what was throwing me off. Thank you so much!

Comment: Oh I see what's happened now.  You're confusing *probability* with *probability density*.  The probability of getting any individual value in the range is in fact $0$; the density tells you something else, which is probably best understood in terms of the Riemann Sum http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum .

Comment: @JeremyRowler glad I could help